# What does "brass" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "brass" mean here?

Time Warner brass

CNN brass

Time Warner ***brass*** had even hired Jamie Kellner.

CNN ***brass*** then announced that in the future journalists would be expected to produce separate reports for its television, radio, and Internet networks.

I am guessing network or media... but not sure what that exactly means..

Comment: Brass (or top brass) has been slang for military officers for a long time, and its use has broadened to refer generally to high-ranking people in any organization.

Comment: Yep, it refers to top-ranking officials, in military, business, and sometimes government.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments and Cambridge, **brass** means:

> **brass**: high-ranking officers in an organization, esp. the military:

Comment: Yes, because the top ranking officers typically had large brass rank insignia whereas the lower ranks’ insignia was typically just cloth

Comment: In Britain we have the term 'brass hats' for senior officers because of the golden coloured decorations on the peaks of their uniform caps. Among police officers that stuff is known as 'fried egg'.